# Is there a way to limit influences-per-vertex weighting?

Tags: animation, rigging, vertex-weights

Apparently there is a limit on how many vertices can be influenced on skeletal meshes on Android and that limit is 4.

Is there a way to set limits for bone-vertices influence in Blender so that when I do weight painting (or better yet assigning weights automatically when parenting mesh to armature) that limit is not exceeded ?

Thanks

Comment: In weight paint mode, there are weight tools in the tools panel on left. one of them is "limit total" which corresponds to what you want. But AFAIK all this have to be done manually

Answer (score -1):

According to this, you can use cleanup to set a max number of influences.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/cleanup.html